# object has no method eq or find

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some elements that are declared sortable in document ready. Later in a function I use toArray to put them into an array. What I want to do it iterate through this array and get the ones that have a specific element in them that I'm looking for. I looped through the array and used .find, but it says that element myarray[index] has no method find, so then I tried myarray.eq(index).find and then it says they do not have method eq. Any help with this would be appreciated. My code is below.

```
  var imageBlocks = $(".imageBlocks").sortable("toArray");
  images = Array();

  for(i = 0; i < imageBlocks.length ; i++)
  {
    image = imageBlocks.eq(i).find(".post_image");
    if(image.length > 0){
      images.push(image); 
    }

  }
```

Comment: Your variable is `imageBlocks` not `$imageBlocks`

Comment: `imageBlocks !== $imageBlocks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like toArrray() just returns an array of strings corresponding to the object's id, rather than an array of the objects themselves which I had though. I fixed this by changing the code to:

```
  var imageBlocks = $(".imageBlocks").sortable("toArray");
  images = Array();

  for(i = 0; i < imageBlocks.length ; i++)
  {
    imageID = $("#"+imageBlocks[i]);
    image = imageID.find(".post_image");

    if(image.length > 0){
      images.push(image);
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
image = imageBlocks[i].find(".post_image");
```

and corrent `$imageBlocks / imageBlocks`

Answer (score 0):

**imageBlocks === $imageBlocks**

```
this should work:

var imageBlocks = $(".imageBlocks").sortable("toArray");
  images = Array();

  for(i = 0; i < imageBlocks.length ; i++)
  {
    image = imageBlocks.eq(i).find(".post_image");
    if(image.length > 0){
      images.push(image); 
    }

  }
```

Comment: Oops, the $ was actually something I tried, and then forgot to take out. imageBlocks.eq(i).find(".post_image"); still generates the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object imageBlock1,imageBlock2,imageBlock3,imageBlock4,imageBlock5 has no method 'eq' "

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your limited scope, I cannot understand why this would not work:

```
var myimages = imageBlocks.filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('.post_Image').length >0;
});
var myArray = myimages.toArray();
```

EDIT: chained:

```
var myArray = imageBlocks.filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('.post_Image').length > 0;
}).toArray();
```

Am I missing something  here?

EDIT: Just to be clear, use for your example; my code above, expanded out in actual use:

```
$(".imageBlocks").filter(function(){
     return $(this).find('.post_Image').length > 0;
}).toArray();
```

I put a fiddle together with the above and some markup so you can see it fully implimented: http://jsfiddle.net/kDNuc/